Calling non-const operator() on a const lambda object
Consider the following code snippet (demo):
const auto lambda = [] () mutable {};
using Lambda = decltype(lambda);

static_assert(!std::is_function_v<Lambda>);
static_assert(std::is_class_v<Lambda>);
void (Lambda::*ptr)() = &Lambda::operator();  // operator() is not const

// Calling non-const method:
lambda();                                     // SURPRISE: this works
// lambda.operator()();                       // error: conversion loses qualifiers


Why does the lambda(); line compile?
It doesn't compile, if we add an = inside the [] of lambda. Why does this make a difference?


Note, that the following two types are the same (demo):
class C;
using CC = const C;
static_assert(std::is_same_v<void (C::*)(), void (CC::*)()>);



Why does the lambda(); line compile?

As you might see with cppinsights
const auto lambda = [] () mutable {};
lambda();

will use function pointer conversion (which is const).
class __lambda_4_25
{
public: 
    inline /*constexpr */ void operator()() {}
    
    using retType_4_25 = void (*)();
    inline constexpr operator retType_4_25 () const noexcept { return __invoke; }
    
private: 
    static inline /*constexpr */ void __invoke() { __lambda_4_25{}.operator()(); }
};
  
const __lambda_4_25 lambda = __lambda_4_25{};
lambda.operator __lambda_4_25::retType_4_25()(); // Conversion here


It doesn't compile, if we add an = inside the [] of lambda. Why does this make a difference?

lambda with capture (even if nothing is actually captured) cannot be converted to function pointer.

Further reading: Why is mutable lambda converted to function pointer instead of calling operator()?
